# how to create columns similar to mysql datatype in sequlize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to create two columns as shown below, with the datetime datatype 
and with same constraints , in sequelize. any ideas?

```
CreatedTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UpdatedTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize by default creates two-time stamps namely `created_at` and `updated_at`. If you want to rename those columns you can rename them as follows -

```
sequelize.define('user', ..., {
  CreatedTime: 'created_at',
  UpdatedTime: 'updated_at',
});
```

If you don't want to use the default attributes then you can create them manually as follows -

```
const User = sequelize.define(
  'User',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      field: 'id'
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      field: 'created_at'
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      onUpdate: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      field: 'updated_at'
    }
  },
  {
    tableName: 'user',
    timestamps: false
  }
);
```

Hope it helps!